# Decode audio stream channels to multiple wavs using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, wav, decode

My goal is to decode an ac3 from avi to multiple wavs - one for each channel, using ffmpeg.

Using

```
ffmpeg.exe -i the.avi -c:a copy the.ac3 the.wav
```

would decode it to a single wav, and typing `the.wavs` won't help...
I know it can be done with other tools, but I want to know how it's achievable with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options):

> You can also extract each channel of an input to specific outputs; the following command extracts two channels of the INPUT audio stream (file 0, stream 0) to the respective OUTPUT_CH0 and OUTPUT_CH1 outputs:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i INPUT -map_channel 0.0.0 OUTPUT_CH0 -map_channel 0.0.1 OUTPUT_CH1
> ```

In your case it'll look something like:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i teh.avi -c:a copy -map_channel 0.0.0 0.wav -map_channel 0.0.1 1.wav
```

Assuming that the ac3 is stream 0 in the avi.

Comment: blahdiblah, thank you pal.

So basically, instead of simply add "s" at the end of ".wav", like eac3to does, you have to specify a command for EACH CHANNEL to output... OH just how much I lov ffmpeg.

Comment: you need to get rid of the `-c:a copy` or it will give you both channels despite the mapping.